# Is is possible to rotate text using nodes near coords?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I'm plotting a ybar, and nodes near coords is ugly.  Is it possible to rotate the text above the bars by 90?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[area legend,
legend pos=north west,
legend columns=4,
legend style={draw=none},
symbolic x coords={D,F,R,M,K,S,C},
major tick length=0cm,
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
ybar,
bar width = 6pt,
]
\addplot[area legend] %[ybar,,fill=blue]  fill=color1
coordinates {(D,0.78) (F,0.23) (R,0.93) (M,0.73) (K,0.00) (S,0.37) (C,0.36)};
\addplot[area legend] %[ybar,,fill=blue]
coordinates {(D,0.52) (F,0.62) (R,0.60) (M,0.56) (K,0.64) (S,0.166) (C,0.170)};
\addplot[area legend] %[ybar,,fill=blue]
coordinates {(D,0.635) (F,0.437) (R,0.744) (M,0.345) (K,0.48) (S,0.652) (C,0.955)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: can you please provide a working example? otherwise it is difficult to give a good answer

Comment: done.  If only I could rotate the text above the bars, it would save a lot of space.

Comment: Please always add a full, compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, not just code fragments. It's just a few lines more (in most cases) and avoids confusion, potential errors and extra works for answerers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can rotate the nodes using

```
every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west}
```

Note that this option needs to be added after `ybar`, since `ybar` overwrites the `every node near coord` style.

The `nodes near coords` do not automatically enlarge the plot area to accommodate them, so you have to do something like `enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2}` to adjust the top border of the plot area.

(Unrequested extra information: The option `area legend` has to be passed to the `addplots`, it is not an `axis` option. To do this for all plots, you have to use the `axis` option `every axis plot post/.style={area legend}`)

[image: pgfplots with rotated labels]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={D,F,R,M,K,S,C},
    major tick length=0cm,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
    nodes near coords,
    ybar,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    bar width = 6pt,
]
\addplot
coordinates {(D,0.78) (F,0.23) (R,0.93) (M,0.73) (K,0.00) (S,0.37) (C,0.36)};
\addplot
coordinates {(D,0.52) (F,0.62) (R,0.60) (M,0.56) (K,0.64) (S,0.166) (C,0.170)};
\addplot
coordinates {(D,0.635) (F,0.437) (R,0.744) (M,0.345) (K,0.48) (S,0.652) (C,0.955)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats fantastic Jake.  Works a treat. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake How  could it be done to rotate the labes `D`, `F`, `R`, `M`, ... in your sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\rotatebox{<angle>}{Text}` (from the already loaded `graphicx`) package to rotate text. More complicated stuff like verbatim text can be rotated using the `{adjustbox}{angle=<angle>}` environment provided by the `adjustbox` package. Simply use these macros inside the node, but TikZ might have own options for it.

Comment: Please reject my edit, it was  a mistake

Comment: I don't see how this helps, nodes near coord automatically generates the text.

Comment: @Iain: In this case I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Iain, @Martin: The general idea is definitely correct, the normal TikZ option `rotate=90` doesn't work in this case. I've used Martin's approach in my answer.

Comment: @Martin,@Jake: Thanks guys, you have been very helpful.

Comment: @Ian: You are welcome. After it turned out that this was useful after all, it would be nice if you take the down-vote back (if its from you). Thanks.

Comment: **+1 from me!**