# Two figures next to each other (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have read a couple of questions that are quite close to mine, but I have no idea how to incorporate them in my code. I have two figures and I would like to have them side by side. Could you give me a hand with this? Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
   \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
    (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
},
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
interval & Eval & Dev \\
Mono     & 19.29  & 31.31 \\
Tri1     & 9.56 & 15.97  \\
Tri2    & 8.16 & 13.86 \\
Tri3   & 10 & 10 \\
}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=.8cm, %ancho barra
        width=9cm, %dimensiones de figura
        height=.5\textwidth,
        legend style={at={(1,1)},
            anchor=north east,legend columns=-1},
        symbolic x coords={Mono, Tri1, Tri2, Tri3},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords, %letricas arriba
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        ymin=0,ymax=35,
        ylabel={WER (\%)},
    ]
    \addplot [draw=black, fill=black] table[x=interval,y=Eval]{\mydata};
    \addplot [draw=black, pattern color = black, pattern = north west lines] table[x=interval,y=Dev]{\mydata};
    \legend{Eval, Dev}
\end{axis}
\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {EN - Tg};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
interval & Eval & Dev \\
Mono     & 20.87  & 32.70 \\
Tri1     & 10.22 & 16.26  \\
Tri2    & 8.38 & 14.87 \\
Tri3   & 10 & 10 \\
}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=.8cm, %ancho barra
        width=9cm, %dimensiones de figura
        height=.5\textwidth,
        legend style={at={(1,1)},
            anchor=north east,legend columns=-1},
        symbolic x coords={Mono, Tri1, Tri2, Tri3},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords, %letricas arriba
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        ymin=0,ymax=38,
        ylabel={WER (\%)},
    ]
    \addplot [draw=black, fill=black] table[x=interval,y=Eval]{\mydata};
    \addplot [draw=black, pattern color = black, pattern = north west lines] table[x=interval,y=Dev]{\mydata};
    \legend{Eval, Dev}
\end{axis}
\node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {EN - Tgpr};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Empty lines indicate paragraph breaks, remove them.

Comment: Depending on your final goal you may want to put them into `\subfigure`s inside a `figure` environment.

Comment: @marmot I followed on your proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Based on [Text placed under figure instead of above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376318) and [Manually Place a Figure in LaTeX (here: End of Chapter/Section)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375068).
- I put you `pgfplots` stuff in external files in order to make the structure of the code clearer (in general a good idea in my opinion).
- Here I use the `float` package in order to place the float manually (`\begin{figure}[H]`) at a specific position (there are opinions *against* that solution).
- You have a weird mixture of absolute and relative dimensions (e. g. `bar width=.8cm` and `height=.5\textwidth`). I did not optimize that - I just changed it a bit until the MWE was ok-ish.
- I also show how to reference the figures (`\ref` and `\label`).

---

### Main Code

`\usepackage{subcaption}` is essential.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{pgfplots__Diagram__1.tex}
        \caption{Subcaption of the left diagram.}
        \label{Fig:SubLeft}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{pgfplots__Diagram__2.tex}
        \caption{Subcaption of the right diagram.}
        \label{Fig:SubRight}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption of both diagrams.}
    \label{Fig:Main}
\end{figure}
```

---

### Full Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

%%%
\begin{filecontents}{pgfplots__Diagram__1.tex}
%
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & Eval & Dev \\
    Mono     & 19.29  & 31.31 \\
    Tri1     & 9.56 & 15.97  \\
    Tri2    & 8.16 & 13.86 \\
    Tri3   & 10 & 10 \\
    }\myDataDiagramOne
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=4mm, 
            width=0.95\textwidth,
            height=50mm,
            legend style={at={(1,1)},
                anchor=north east,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Mono, Tri1, Tri2, Tri3},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords, %letricas arriba
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=35,
            ylabel={WER (\%)},
        ]
        \addplot [draw=black, fill=black] table[x=interval,y=Eval]{\myDataDiagramOne};
        \addplot [draw=black, pattern color = black, pattern = north west lines] table[x=interval,y=Dev]{\myDataDiagramOne};
        \legend{Eval, Dev}
    \end{axis}
    \node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {EN - Tg};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{filecontents}

%%%
\begin{filecontents}{pgfplots__Diagram__2.tex}
%
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & Eval & Dev \\
    Mono     & 20.87  & 32.70 \\
    Tri1     & 10.22 & 16.26  \\
    Tri2    & 8.38 & 14.87 \\
    Tri3   & 10 & 10 \\
    }\myDataDiagramTwo
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=4mm, 
            width=0.95\textwidth,
            height=50mm,
            legend style={at={(1,1)},
                anchor=north east,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Mono, Tri1, Tri2, Tri3},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords, %letricas arriba
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=38,
            ylabel={WER (\%)},
        ]
        \addplot [draw=black, fill=black] table[x=interval,y=Eval]{\myDataDiagramTwo};
        \addplot [draw=black, pattern color = black, pattern = north west lines] table[x=interval,y=Dev]{\myDataDiagramTwo};
        \legend{Eval, Dev}
    \end{axis}
    \node[above,font=\large\bfseries] at (current bounding box.north) {EN - Tgpr};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376318
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

Text before.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{pgfplots__Diagram__1.tex}
        \caption{Subcaption of the left diagram.}
        \label{Fig:SubLeft}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{pgfplots__Diagram__2.tex}
        \caption{Subcaption of the right diagram.}
        \label{Fig:SubRight}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption of both diagrams.}
    \label{Fig:Main}
\end{figure}

Text after. In \figurename~\ref{Fig:Main} there are two subfigures, nameley Subfigure~\ref{Fig:SubLeft} and \ref{Fig:SubRight}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Dr.ManuelKuehner. Anyway, how could I change the size of the numbers upper part of the bars?

Comment: This is a different question and I am already in bed :)

Comment: Ohhh Do not worry @Dr.ManuelKuehner. Anyway, thanks for the first answer

Comment: @little_mice You could just do `every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west,
   font=\small\sffamily},`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22519/121799). If you drop the `rotate` and `anchor` stuff, it won't get rotated, but probably the text will be too wide then.